# Force selected coefficients to be non-negative in ridge regression

Tags: python, ridge-regression, constrained-regression

I want to fit a ridge regression on ~ 47 variables and 12 of them I want to be `positive` (or at least non-negative).

I'm using sklearn and doing the following:

```
    ridge = Ridge(positive=True)
    parameters = {'alpha':10**np.linspace(10,-2,300)*0.5}
    ridgeCV_fitted_local = GridSearchCV(
        ridge,
        parameters,
        scoring=scoring,
        cv=cv
    ).fit(X_train_local_cp,y_train_local)
```

Now, this will make so that other coefficients that can and should be negative will now become at least 0. Sure, the coefficients that I'm subsetting are also 0 (or at least positive) which is what I intended, but certain variables like "covid" that I'm using now go to 0 when it makes sense that they're negative.

Is there a way to subset just a few coefficients to be non-negative?

I don't think it would be viable from a statistics POV to fit a general ridge regression first, remove the subset of coefficients and replace them with the non-negative coefficients coming from a new ridge regression fit using `positive=True`.

Is there anyway to "swtich on or off" the `positive=True` argument when the model fits the subset of features I'm interested to not be 0?

Comment: a hack would be to multiply columns by -1 which you want to allow a negative coefficient for but are currently being estimated as 0.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you for your input! However, using the ridge argument positive = True, wouldn't that just put the coefficients back to 0?

Comment: The coefficient would be positive in the model summary, you just have to remember that it's the coefficient associated with "negative X" rather than "X".